# Xamarin "Aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

By creating an Android project with the API 19 (4.4.2) in Visual Studio 2015, when I want to start the application shown me these errors.

**Look**

[image: Look]

**Error 1:** "aapt.exe" exited with code -**1073741819.** APP_Activity_Sync C: \ Program Files (x86) \ MSBuild \ Xamarin \ Android \ Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 1665

**Error 2:** The file "obj \ Debug \ android \ bin \ packaged_resources" does not exist. APP_Activity_Sync C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 1691

I have all the files downloaded API19 with the SDK Manager.

**SDK Details API19**

[image: SDK Details API19]

Somebody wants something similar happened, what is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was getting this problem as well, the above solution didn't work for me.
What did work was:

1. Remove Android SDK Build-tools v24
2. Install Android SDK Build-tools v23.0.3 and install

[image: SDK Manager]

**EDIT:**

There's a new version of Android SDK build-tools "24.0.1". Upgrading to that version worked for me as well

Comment: This solution worked for me. The softwares I have got installed are Visual Studio 2015, Xamarin4.0.3.214 and Android SDK up to API 23 installed. Hope this helps people who are having similar problems.

Comment: That was the only solution it worked for me, for some reason Xamarin is not working with revision 24 !

Comment: This worked perfectly for me as well! Now if I could just figure out why all my APKs get "You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again." from the Store even though they should successful!

Answer (score 6):

I spend a day fix it problem by

Remove  this 2 Package from SDK Manager

[image]

And Move everything into C:\ as Project Root

Comment: this fix doesnt work for me, however following the instructions on here did https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28181/android-build-tools-21-0-1-aapt-exe-exited-with-code-1073741819-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

I fix this error by changing the name of the image in resource file.actually i was taken an image name like this "abc_jkl.png".After that i change the name to Abc, and resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

Same problem as above... But uninstalling Android sdk built tools 24 worked for me
-> **Uninstall SDK Build tools 24**
-> **Rebuild your Solution**